# User \"system:serviceaccount:infini-system:default\" cannot get resource \"postgreses\" in API group \"kubedb.com\" in the namespace \"default\""

Tags: kubernetes

I am getting the following error in the logs of k8s controller. Can anyone help?
I have custom resource Postgres that I am using it for my timescaledb pod.

```
postgreses.kubedb.com \"my-infini-timescaledb\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:infini-system:default\" cannot get resource \"postgreses\" in API group \"kubedb.com\" in the namespace \"default\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't attach any RBAC rules to your `infini-system` service account in the default namespace which your pod is running.
Please configure your RBAC according to https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Make sure you provide get permissions to resource `postgreses` in API Group `kubedb.com`